# Check if URL pass variable using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, url, variables, parameters

How can I check if URL contains variable or not? I have my function like this

My 2nd problem is, let says the URL already pass the lang variable, something like this (http://index.php?id=23&lang=en) i want that when they run this function again it will replace the lang variable to the new on instead of add new lang variable like this (http://index.php?id=23&lang=en&lang=jp)

```
function menu_goto(newvalue)
{
var baseurl = window.location.href ;

var langwithpara = "&lang=" + newvalue;
var langwopara = "?lang=" + newvalue;

    if (newvalue != 0) {
        if(baseurl.match(/?/)){
        alert ('123');
        location.href = baseurl + langwithpara ;
        }
        else{
        alert ('456');
        location.href = baseurl + langwopara ;
        }
    }
}
```

My new coding (work)

```
function menu_goto(newvalue)
{
  var baseurl = window.location.href ;
  var url = baseurl + ( (baseurl.match(/\?/))? '&':'?' ) + 'lang=' + newvalue;

  location.href = url ;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is probably the missing escaping of "?" in your RegExp:

```
if (baseurl.match(/\?/)) { // ...
```

a bit shorter would be:

```
var url = baseurl + ( (baseurl.match(/\?/))? '&':'?' ) + 'lang=' + newvalue;
```

You would probably want to clean any param "lang" before, so it doesn't become an array by multiple occurrence.

It would probably better to assemble the url anew like

```
function menu_goto(newvalue) {
    var params = {};
    if (self.location.search) {
      var pairs = self.location.search.substring(1).split("&"); // skip the "?"
      for (var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
        var parts = pairs[i].split('=');
        params[parts[0]] = parts[1];
      }
    }
    params.lang = newvalue;
    var query = new Array();
    for (var p in params) query.push(p + '=' + params[p]);
    var url = self.location.protocol + '//' + self.location.host + self.location.pathname
              + '?' + query.join('&');

    self.location.href = url;
}
```

Here is yet another solution using RegExps:

```
function menu_goto2(newvalue) {
    var url = self.location.href;
    url = url.replace(/#.*/, ''); // clean any hash at end
    url = url.replace(/[&\?]lang=[^&]*/, ''); // clean any param lang and its value
    // we might have had two or more params and "lang" was the first one
    // then we might have lost the "?" => replace first "&" by "?"
    if (url.indexOf('?') < 0 && url.indexOf('&') >= 0) url = url.replace(/&/, '?');
    url += ( url.match(/\?/)? '&':'?') + 'lang=' + newvalue; // add the new param lang
    self.location.href = url;
}
```

Which could be shortened to

```
function menu_goto3(newvalue) {
    var url = self.location.href.replace(/#.*/, '').replace(/[&\?]lang=[^&]*/, '');
    if (url.indexOf('?') < 0 && url.indexOf('&') >= 0) url = url.replace(/&/, '?');
    url += ( url.match(/\?/)? '&':'?') + 'lang=' + newvalue;
    self.location.href = url;
}
```

Comment: My 2nd problem is, let says the URL already pass the lang variable, something like this (http://index.php?id=23&lang=en) i want that when they run this function again it will replace the lang variable to the new on instead of add new lang variable like this (http://index.php?id=23&lang=en&lang=jp)

Comment: @MiszJieha This is exactly what the second part is all about. What it does: It takes the query-string (in document.location.search), splits it in pairs, which are then stored as key-value associations in the object "params". (So there will be param.id == "23", param.lang == "jp", etc.) Now we just overwrite "param.lang" (anyway, if it has been set before or not). Then we compose a clean, new url by assembling the parts of the base-url (minus the search-part or any hash-marks) and add the new query-string to it (joined from the key-value pairs in the "params" object).

Comment: Continued -- The beauty of it: Once we reach `params.lang = newval;`, you can set any params you would like to set or clear any params (e.g. clearing "page" would be `delete params.page`). It works, regardless, if there have been any parameters set at all or not, just the same.

Comment: FYI i'm new in javascript, i just wonder where should i put that coding.
My working coding as per edited on my post. should i put after var url...and what does self. mean?

Comment: I've just put the code in a function. `self` refers to the global context, in the browser it is just the same as `window` (but it's a bit more general). On the location-object: `location.href` is the same as the sum of its following parts: `location.protocol` (e.g.: "http:"), `"//"`, `location.host` (e.g.: "stackoverflow.com"), `location.pathname` (e.g.: "/questions/18995929/..."), `location.search` (e.g: "?lang=en") and `location.hash` (e.g.: "#18996039"). (Or short: href = protocol+"//"+host+pathname+search+hash, where search is the query-string including the "?" or empty.)

Comment: i'm getting this in my url whenever i change the language more than 1 time '?l=undefined&a=undefined&n=undefined&g=undefined&=&e=undefined&lang=jp' what does var pairs = self.location.search.substring(1); do?separate each varible or separate each letter?since if i alert pairs it will popup one letter to one letter.

Comment: @MiszJieha Sorry, there was a typo. It must be `params.lang = newvalue;` (the same name as used as for the argument in `function menu_goto(newvalue) {`)! Now tested and working as in the answer (updated).

Answer (score 1):

window.location is actually an object, it has a 'search' property that make it easier to parse the query string.

```
function getParam(param){
    var qs = window.location.search.substring(1).split('&');
    var qsp;
    for (p in qs){
        qsp = qs[p].split('=');
        if (qsp[0] == param) return qsp[1]; 
    }
    return null;
}
```

to check for a specific parameter :

```
var value = getParam('name');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) method for this

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("your value") != -1) {
     alert("It contains");
 }
 else {
    alert("Nope");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function menu_goto(newvalue)
        {
        var baseurl = window.location.href ;
        var langwithpara = "&lang=" + newvalue;
        var langwopara = "?lang=" + newvalue;

            if (newvalue != 0) {
                if(baseurl.match(/\?/)){ // change /?/ to /\?/
                alert('123');
                location.href = baseurl + langwithpara ;
                }
                else{
                alert('456');
                location.href = baseurl + langwopara ;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: My 2nd problem is, let says the URL already pass the lang variable, something like this (http://index.php?id=23&lang=en) i want that when they run this function again it will replace the lang variable to the new on instead of add new lang variable like this (http://index.php?id=23&lang=en&lang=jp)